# Sox (sound exchange) on mac PPC 10.4 installation questions

Tags: sox

I am trying to get to grips with SOX on mac.

I know how to program php.  But i need to use sox to add audio water marks to mp3 files.

I have been unable to find any ready made scipts for mac.   So I suppose i will need to write one myself.

Tho i dont know how to program any Ruby or python so i am not sure how hard it will be.

The main problems i am having are.  I downloaded sox for mac.  My mac is a ppc G5.  When i try to run SOX 14-4.   It gives me a -bash cannot execute binary file message.

Is this because the SOX 14-4 is for intel mac?  and i might need an earlier version of SOX?

If not how can i use the SOX on my mac.  How do i install it?

And also then how will i be able to install it on a Virtual server running linux?

Sorry for big basic question..  I am new.   I would like to learn Ruby tho..  Because i like the sound of the name.

Comment: what is the download link you used to get sox?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sox/files/latest/download?source=files

Comment: ^^ that was the download link.   Just the standard link from the sox page...