# Converting .aiff to .wav in SoX

Tags: audio, sox

I have multiple files in a directory that are in .aiff format, and I would like to convert them to .wav using SoX. I have tried the code on [this](https://memory.psych.mun.ca/tech/snippets/sox-convert.shtml) website, which is as follows

```
theFiles = `/Users/me/RainbowAiff/*.aiff`; 
for eachFile in $theFiles; do v1=${eachFile%*.aiff}; 
oldFile="$v1.aiff"; newFile = "$v1.wav"; 
echo oldFile $oldFile; echo newFile $newFile; sox $oldFile $newFile; done
```

and [this](https://gist.github.com/jesusgollonet/5451477) website, which is as follows

```
for i in `/Users/me/RainbowAiff/ *.aiff`; do echo -e "$i"; sox $i $i.wav; echo -e "$i.wav"; done;
```

but I get an error message in both instances that says "cannot execute binary file". What could be the source of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incompatible binary files cause this error, [see this question](https://superuser.com/questions/724301/how-to-solve-bash-cannot-execute-binary-file).

If the outputs from `file sox` and `uname -a` commands tell that there is a discrepancy between the binary file and your operating system, i.e., x86 vs. ARM, you need to find the correct binary for SoX. Although there is no SoX release since 2015, check [this](http://sox.sourceforge.net/Main/Links) and [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sox/files/sox/) to find a version that is compatible with your system.

The problem is also related to the file attributes of the sox. In order to give it the executable attribute, simply go to the folder where sox is located and run `chmod +x sox` command (you need root access first).

Comment: The output of `file sox` is `Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64` and the output of `uname -a` is `14.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Tue Apr 11 16:12:42 PDT 2017; root:xnu-2782.50.9.2.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64` Are these not compatible? (I am unfamiliar with binary files). Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am not a Mac user, unfortunately, I am not familiar with it. They both seem to be 64-bits, though. Can you try switching to root user with `su` command and go to the directory in which sox is located, then run `chmod +x sox`? Then try running it again, preferably with `sudo sox`, with root permissions. Also, people seem to have a similar issue in Mac, so you might want to try installing an older version of sox, which might be compatible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499871/sox-sound-exchange-on-mac-ppc-10-4-installation-questions

Comment: This worked, but now I'm receiving a syntax error. I suppose that should be a separate question. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. May I ask: Is the `chmod +x sox` or installing an older version helped to run it? The reason I am asking is that I can edit my answer so that it covers all the relevant steps.

Comment: The `chmod +x sox` is what seemed to work, or at least give me a different error message.

Answer (score 1):

The two snippets you linked to looks a little sketchy to me with their use of `ls` and `echo`.
`echo -e` might in fact be what gave you the syntax error, as OSX (BSD) `echo` does not have an `-e` option. (type `man echo` into the terminal to see).

I took the liberty of assembling an alternative one-liner, based around `find` and its `-exec` option.

```
find -E . -maxdepth 1 -iregex '.*\.(aif|aiff)' -exec bash -c '$0 "$1" "${1%.*}.wav"' sox {} \;
```

To explain it:

- `find`: can find about anything
- `-E`: enables [extended regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended)*
- `.`: starts in current working directory. Can be replaced with relative or absolute path
- `-maxdepth 1`: looks only in the first directory layer. Replace 1 with 2 to also find files within folders, with 3 to also find files within folders within folders …
  Removing this option will enable full recursion (find files all the way down)
- `-iregex`: use case-insensitive regular expressions
- `'.*\.(aif|aiff)'`: match anything that starts with anything (`.`) at any length (`*`), followed by a period (`\.`) and the strings 'aif' or 'aiff' (or 'AIF', 'AIFF', 'aiFF' …) (`(aif|aiff)`)
- `-exec bash -c` : execute the following in a non-interactive bash shell

Right around here it gets a bit more complicated

- `'$0 "$1" "${1%.*}.wav"'`: this is the call to be run inside the bash shell. `$0` will expand to the [program name](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html). `"$1"` will expand to the first (and in this case, only) argument, enclosed in double quotes in case of white-spaces. `"${1%.*}.wav"` will also expand to the first argument, except it will [strip away the last period and everything after](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), before tagging on '.wav' at the end. Effectively replacing the file extension.
- `sox {}`: these are the arguments passed to the shell call. The first (`sox`) is the program we want to use, referred to as `$0` within the call. The second (`{}`) is whatever file `find` has found, and referred to as `$1` within the shell call

That's quite a mouthful and I'm no expert, so there might be some mistakes in what I've written, though the general outline should be solid.

<sub>*This is OSX specific, a less pretty but more portable option would be:</sub>

```
find . -maxdepth 1 \( -iname "*.aif" -o -iname "*.aiff" \) -exec bash -c '$0 "$1" "${1%.*}.wav"' sox {} \;
```